# New Database Structure

Tags: database

I was discussing with some colleagues today about how a lot of files, folders and computer structures that we use and access is in the form of Hierarchical. Yes there is also relationship database but my idea is slightly different. My thought is to do a reverse Hierarchical structure where there is one location that is a "at rest hardened encryption" that is accessed via users that are properly tagged to the information but also must pass multi factor acknowledgment to access the information. So for example User logs into their computer -> logs into the website they are accessing with this new structure -> all files that are tagged with their tag associated is in view to them in one location -> on attempt to open or access a file a request for multi factor authentication is sent and if passed access is granted if failed redirected back to the previous page. I made a diagram with a web page that builds SQL databases on their page. However sadly I am not sure if it is correct or not.

https://app.sqldbm.com/SQLServer/Share/Ek-gVjYt2cTW8rxQo22OJ0GFrngIE8md_DYjF4jNYw0

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking someone to verify your system design?

Comment: My apologies, i am asking if the database design i made is logical at all. Also if the idea it's self makes logical sense.